# How do I get Interface Bundle to deliver previous date to DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, date, android-fragments, bundle, android-datepicker

I have a DatePickerDialog that opens in a fragment.  On first open, the dialog's default date displays today's date.  The user then selects a date.  When the dialog is dismissed, I set an EditText line with the user selected date.

The next time the dialog opens (because the user wants to edit their previously selected date), I want to show the user's previously selected date as the default date, not today's date.  I've set up an interface from the fragment to the activity with a Bundle.  Also, not sure my emptiness test on "year" in Fragment's OnCreateDialog is working properly.  Please advise.

partial DatePickerFragment file:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

private int currentyear;
private int currentmonth;
private int currentday;

public DatePickerFragment() {
}

public interface OnDateEnteredListener {
     void OnDateEntered(int year, int month, int day);
}
OnDateEnteredListener mListener;


// Set up a Calendar object that will capture the current date for the DatePickerDialog to use.
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Bundle datebundle = this.getArguments();
    currentyear = datebundle.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    currentmonth = datebundle.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    currentday = datebundle.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

if(currentyear != 0){
        DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this.getActivity(), this, currentyear, currentmonth, currentday);
        dateDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(true);
        dateDialog.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(false);
        dateDialog.setTitle("Select a Due Date");
        return dateDialog;
    }
    else {
        // Create three variables to capture the current date.
        currentyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        currentmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        currentday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // Create a DatePickerDialog which is a simple dialog containing a DatePicker.  Use the current date
        // as the default date in the DatePicker.  The new instance of DatePickerDialog is created by passing
        // 5 parameters/arguments to the constructor and returning it.
        DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this.getActivity(), this, currentyear, currentmonth, currentday);
        dateDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(true);
        dateDialog.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(false);
        dateDialog.setTitle("Select a Due Date");
        return dateDialog;
    }
}


public void onDateSet (DatePicker view,int year, int month, int day) {
     mListener.OnDateEntered(year,month,day);
...

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

partial Activity file:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerFragment.OnDateEnteredListener {

  int currentyear;
  int currentmonth;
  int currentday;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.input);

    fListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(R.id.FEditText);

    fListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus && (fListenerEditText.getText().length() == 0)) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        Bundle datebundle = new Bundle();
              datebundle.putInt("YEAR", currentyear);
              datebundle.putInt("MONTH", currentmonth);
              datebundle.putInt("DAY", currentday);
              newFragment.setArguments(datebundle);
              newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
           }
        }
    });

  @Override
  public void onDateEntered(int year, int month, int day) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you call the dialog, you should get the date from the `EditText`, parse the text to date and set it to current date, then on your dialog `onCreate()` just get the current date

Comment: Ok but how would I do that?  The first time the dialog is created the EditText is empty and I want today's date to show.  Then the user selects a date.  The next time the the user wants to edit the previously selected date I would be able to use EditText.  But how would I do in onCreate()?

Comment: The first time you run, you just call the dialog, and the dialog show with today's date, which you already declared inside your 'else statement'. That's all for the dialog. Then user select the date, you set the `EditText` to the date selected. Which mean your dialog fragment don't have to check for previous date, just display the date get from cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), month and day. Because you can set the current date using cal.set() before you open the dialog

Comment: Ok so use cal.set() in the fragment before onCreateDialog?  Or do you mean use cal.set() in the activity?

Comment: Yes on the activity, then when you get the date using cal.get() in dialog it will return the date you set

Comment: So in the activity just do a simple emptiness test on the EditText.  If empty, use today's date and use cal.set() to notify the fragment.  Use cal.get() in the fragment to get today's date and set it for the dialog.  If not empty (because there is a previously selected date), then use cal.set() to notify the fragment to use the previously selected date.  Am I correct?

Comment: If empty you can just set nothing, because it will get today's date by default. For if not empty, you're correct.

Comment: Ok great.  Do I use cal.get() before onCreateDialog method or is cal.get() used within onCreateDialog?

Comment: within `onCreateDialog()`

Comment: Nice.  Question:  does parsing the text to date create an int so that I can easily test it >  0?    I have been using "getText().length()==0" on EditText and I am now wondering whether parsing or length test is better.

Comment: OR you can use `.matches()`. For example, `txtDate.getText().toString().matches("")`, to check whether it's empty.

Comment: Ok.  Do I still need to use a Bundle and setArguments with cal.set() for the year, month and day or just use cal.set() for year, month and day?

Comment: No need, Bundle is no longer needed, just use cal.set()

Comment: Great...I haven't use set and get before and am new to Android.  Thank you for your time and answering all of my questions.  Upvoting your comments now.  Cheers.

Comment: I posted the answer and can you please upvote it and mark it as answer since upvoting comments won't increase reputations, thanks and hope I helped you.

Comment: Will do.  I have listed one more question for you.  It is listed below your answer, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If previous date not found, show the dialog along with today's date using `cal.get()`
2. User select the date,set the `EditText` to the date selected.
3. If previous date found, parse the text from `EditText` to date format, set it to current date using `cal.set()`, and display the dialog using `cal.get()`

You can check whether the `EditText` is empty using `.matches()` method.

For example,

```
if(txtDate.getText().toString().matches(""))
         // txtDate was empty
```

Comment: Ok, I will give this a try.

Comment: If the EditText is empty (no previously selected date) then wouldn't I have to use currentyear = cal.set(Calendar.YEAR); currentmonth = cal.set(Calendar.MONTH); and currentday = cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); to set today's date in the dialog?  you had mentioned the dialog would get today's date by default.

Comment: Ya, no need to set it, it will retrieve today's date by default.

Comment: One more question.  Do cal.set() from activity and cal.get() in the fragment require the use of the interface and listener or can I remove all of that code?

Comment: No needed, just declare `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();` then `cal.set()` and `cal.get()` can be use

Comment: Ok great that should do it.

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to get() date from the activity where I set() the date.
See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706796/how-do-i-set-the-default-date-in-a-datepickerdialog-in-my-fragment-from-the-host.  Please advise.