# How do I set the default date in a DatePickerDialog in my fragment from the host activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-calendar, android-datepicker

So I created a calendar object "c" in the Activity and set the date to February 29, 2016.  I want the fragment dialog to load that date as the default date.  What am I missing here?  Do I need to delete the fragment calendar object 'cal'?  If so, in the fragment onCreateDialog how do I reference or get() the date from the set() method in the Activity?

from Activity file:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 29);

    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

from the Fragment file:

```
...
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        currentyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        currentmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        currentday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this.getActivity(), this, currentyear,currentmonth,currentday);
       return dateDialog;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Calendar c` you set in your Activity is different from the `Calendar cal` in your fragment, they are two different instances.

I suggest you pass the year, month and day to the fragment using a `Bundle`, so you would want to go:

`Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putInt("...", "..."); //
DialogFragment df = new DialogFragment();
df.setArguments(data);`

Then in your `onCreateDialog` in the fragment, retrieve the data using:

```
int year = getArguments("...");
```

Comment: Ok I thought 2 calendar objects was wrong.  Do I have to set up callback listeners (an interface) between fragment and activity?  Or will Bundle's putInt and setArguments work for the Activity with getInt and getArguments for the fragment?

Comment: To pass data from Activity to Fragment, "setArguments" and "getArguments" would suffice; to pass data from Fragment to Activity, I do suggest that you use a callback listener!

Comment: Interesting.  Ok, another commenter suggested I can use set() and get() methods without a Bundle or listeners.  If you don't mind and have a few minutes can you let me know what you think of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686320/how-do-i-get-interface-bundle-to-deliver-previous-date-to-datepickerdialog

Comment: See the following [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Implement), it is the official Android Developers website and it suggests  a callback interface when communicating between Activity and Fragment :)

Comment: Yes, I read that and tried to set up listener with no luck and not sure how to diagnose problem.  Question:  if I receive a date in the fragment with a Bundle to load in a datepickerdialog will I have to communicate back to the Activity with the listener for an EditText in the xml file?  Or can I just use onDateSet in the fragment and I don't have to set up a listener interface?

Comment: Make sure your fragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener interface, then using the onDateSet method would be sufficient :)

Comment: Also please kindly accept my answer if it helped :)

Comment: Accepted but so far I've received 5 or 6 different ways to tackle the datepicker issue from stackoverflow commenters.  Imo, each one is too complex, too much code, doesn't work or causes other issues. For me, solving these thorny issues is best achieved by keeping the code as lightweight and as simple as possible.  To date, I have not found a lightweight, simple solution.  After having read probably 250 blogposts on the issue or similar, it has taken me much longer than I anticipated for such a simple request.  I am still working on it and will not give up until I find a solution.